# Automatic SSL certificates with Oplon's LBL

Tags: ssl-certificate, load-balancing

When using Oplon's load balancer, is there any way to setup SSL certificates with automatic enrollment and updates? For instance with let's encrypt service or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

YES, you can find documentation in the links below

https://www.oplon.net/en/product/lbl-adc-en/

https://www.oplon.net/en/knowledge-base/acme-sslcertificate-2/

Furthermore, from version 9.9.7 you can use REST commands to manage thousands of certificates and obtain lists of certificates to centrally manage the expiration and renew.

It's never been easier to create and manage SSL digital certificates!

[image]